# Is it useful to add more sections in our profil's comments tab?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments

My question is a little mix of discussion and feature request, I was thinking that maybe adding sections like "votes", "activity", "newest" ... to the comments tab in our profiles could be useful.

For me as an example, that will be great if I can check the activity of some Q/A where I contributed by comments (specially for comments on an answers and not on a question), or to verify which of my comments was more appreciated ...

What do you think?

### UPDATE:

As asked per comments, I can see that working in the same thing questions work, the votes section order the qestions by most voted so comments will be ordered with the same logic, regarding activity that tab will be ordered by the Q/A activity in which our comment exist, and for newest it's already clear :)

I'm talking about something like that in the comments tab:

[image]

Comment: Comments are **not** considered important within SO (which is why they're in *activities -> comments*, rather than getting their own tab, and don't appear on *summary*), I doubt any [tag:feature-request] to add more commenting functionality will gain much traction. That said, could you clarify exactly how you see this working?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for replying, I updated my answer hope I'm clear now :)

Comment: wait you can see your comments from your profile?! that's news to me, I always assumed they were so unimportant no one implemented a way to see them from your profile :P

Comment: @Patrice hahaha ok I understand, you guys saw them extremly unimportant :) But I really don't agree, so many questions were answered only within comments, also if they are really so unimportant why there is badges for them?

Comment: @tarik It's more a feeling taken from Stack Exchange as a whole. Comments have always been second class citizens here. I don't necessarily agree, but it's something you get used to, because it won't change

Comment: @Patrice thats true, I think you are right. However, I will let the question just in case.